# Windows Azure Tools for Visual Studio csdef and cscfg do not match

Tags: visual-studio-2010, azure, azure-configuration

I am completely losing my mind over this as I have a lot of work to do and I can't accomplish anything right now. Something happened and now every time I try to run our project in the Windows Azure emulator via Visual Studio it pops up the error as in the question title.

"Windows Azure Tools for Visual Studio
.cscfg and .csdef do not match"

I have not touched these files ever, I also reinstalled azure tools (several times!) in order to make sure they were completely default, and they are. I honestly am at a complete loss here, I have no idea what could be causing this. A google search for that error turned up absolutely no hits which is bizarre.

Comment: While you may not have consciously changed anything, have you checked that your .csfg and .csdef do match?

Comment: Could you post the content of your cscfg and csdef files (removing the  sensitive data)?

Comment: I have just encountered exactly the same error as you.  Similarly, I did not change the files.  In fact, I checked out an earlier version of my solution from my Git repository that I know worked for sure, with the same error.  So this looks like a bug in the Azure emulator.  But how to fix it!

Comment: same error after 3 years now. Any work around for this?

Comment: The same problem i have

Answer (score 5):

For me it was an empty

```
<ConfigurationSettings>
</ConfigurationSettings>
```

block I had to insert into both my cscfg files.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.

To solve that I've changed the configuration from x86 to AnyCPU. It´s working fine now.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 2):

I too experienced this problem and was frustrated with the lack of info on it. However, I found that the easy solution was to remove the role from the azure project and re-add it. Unless you have an insane amount of config settings to manage, this is a fairly quick and painless process.

Answer (score 2):

Our issue was fixed by commenting out the load balanced endpoint in csdef.

Comment: Same here - although if you need the loadBalancer attribute, then what do you do then?

Answer (score 1):

After having the exact same problem as you with the exact same symptoms, I found that manually starting the Compute Engine emulator like so:

> System Tray > Right click Windows Azure Emulator >  Start Compute Emulator

magically allowed me to run my Azure solution once more.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if "serviceName" is the same in both files (even if you did not touch anything).
This is the basic parameter that MUST match in both files.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee758710.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In my case I could see two build configurations ( .cscfg files ) in the solution explorer within Visual Studio plus the .csdef file. However - when I looked at the actual files in that folder - there was an additional ServiceConfiguration.cscfg file which I needed to update.

Note: I added configuration parameters and these were missing from that ServiceConfiguration.cscfg file. In my output window it showed which parameters were missing.